# "Your Answer to the question at the top of this page"

Tags: feature-request, answers

I have seen many an "answer" which is actually a question loosely related to the topic of OP's question.
Most of them are by new and low rep users. I assume, without blaming those new users, that they have the misunderstanding of being in a forum, where people just discuss a topic. That is, of course, wrong and they need to learn about how Stack Overflow is actually meant to be used.

I speculate that another attribute of those new users might be relevant, that they are not entirely fluent in English. I myself am not a native English speaker. I think that the misunderstanding could be rooted for this group of users in the fact that "Your Answer" (which is, of course, the headline of the corresponding entry field) is not explicitly enough asking for an answer to OP's question.

Those users can read something more like "your participation in this discussion"; especially if they have a burning need for help and the impression that the "chatting" people could easily help them. In order to help those users notice their misunderstanding, or maybe to actually prevent it, I think that a somewhat subtle change could help a lot. I propose therefore to change:

> Your Answer

to

> Your Answer to the question at the top of this page

or to something else, better phrased by people with more talent at phrasing in English, but with the same idea of being more obvious.

---

Update (thanks Abhishek Gurjar):

I just learned that, for new and low rep users, there is actually a very explicit and helpful information popup, or banner - after they start typing an answer. Admittedly, this is a lot towards what I want. However, I am trying to walk the path of subtle influence. I imagine that once they started typing (maybe more so in a foreign language) they can easily enter an over-focused, almost blind state. Please do not take this as an insult, I really only mean the cognitively challenging situation in which those users are additionally burdened by their probably desperate need for help.

Also, I would not bother too much with this speculation, if I did not see such a baffling lot of "not an answer" problems. The fact that the mentioned banner does exist, is, to me, actually a reason for trying to add a different approach for helping those users, not against.

Update (using Kendra's nice input as devil's advocate):

Why is "Your answer to the question ..." better than "Your Answer"?
I am basing my proposal on quite a large number of observed "questions-where-an-answer-should-be". Some of them additionally indicate (using phrases like "above answer") that the posters are not even aware that the order of answers is unpredictable, because of preferences in sorting. This matches a perception as more of a forum or chat than the Q&A design of Stack Overflow.

All of them match the "your participation to this discussion" interpretation better than the "Your Answer" reality. I hope to contradict the misinterpretation by closely pairing the words "question" and "answer". Thereby to stress the Q&A design to contrast the forum perception.
This, I assume, is a more relevant "nudge" for users who linguistically perceive the site in a less precise way, i.e. users for whom English is not their first language. For them, "answer" is more easily confused with "your statement", "your view", "your opinion", "your experience" than with "answer to the question" or even only "answer to question".

Update (picking up input by Radiodef and jkdev):

By referring to "*the question at the top of the page*" or by actually quoting it, the phrasing of that question is quite relevant. The proposed change (especially in the shape proposed by jkdev) admittedly gets a slightly weird twist, in case of titles which are not really a question in the linguistic sense. There are some really good, helpful, catchy and self-explaining titles out there (please excuse me including some which I have written myself by editing questions) which are, strictly speaking, not questions. They do for example not end in a "?". This is not saying that they are a problem. Just that they get strange when quoted or referred to by the "Your answer to ..." version of the input field label.

The answer by jkdev, which I very much like for "*How to exit Vim editor?*", I am in two minds about, when it quotes:

> I need some help with this code, which does not work and it is very weird. Any suggestions are welcome.

I think that "*the question at the top of this page*" can equally well refer to the whole thing, including the body. In my opinion it stays quite valid to ask for "*Your answer to the question*" if the question is actually only in the full description, even if not in the title. This does not work so well if the title is quoted. (By the way, this is why I do not accept the answer, even if I like the idea.)

Staying with my own assumption, that the target audience might not be very fluent in English, I cannot of course entirely rely on this somewhat advanced interpretation. The intended effect (of getting new, possibly non-English users to understand that they should answer, not ask) might be lost in these cases of non-question title and non-English users. For these cases I would fall back to "it is worth a try" and hope for an improvement in many other cases.

Comment: But when user tries to type their answer site already provide them pop up banner mentioning them to be specific and other things.

Comment: It only appears to new users and user having rep less than 100rep or something. try it in incognito mode.

Comment: I mean to say it will show to new user/guest user or user less than 100 rep so if you try any of these way you will get a banner.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar Thanks for your valuable input. I even considered deleting my post. But I realised that in my opinion it gives a different angle and actually more reason.

Comment: You know it's an issue when you have a [dedicated room to flagging NAAs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Natty&user=6817005&room=111347). It really would be nice to reduce this number.

Comment: Maybe instead of `Your answer to the question at the top of this page` it could display the actual title of the question. For instance: `Your answer to "How to exit the Vim editor?"`

Comment: Definitely like the sound of that @jkdev, post as an answer?

Comment: @jkdev I like that. It works well for short actual questions, ideally with a "?" at the end. However, for longer "I need some help with this code, which does not work and it is very weird. Any suggestions are welcome." it does not work so well. Maybe a combination has the benefits of your proposal and is robust against suboptimally phrased titles: "Your answer to the question at the top of this page: 'How to exit Vim?' "

Comment: @JakeSteam Good idea. I've posted an answer now.

Comment: Devil's advocate here, so let me ask: If "Your answer" isn't enough to say "This needs to be an answer", then why is "Your answer to this question" that much better? Can you expand on that idea a bit?

Comment: @Kendra well, apparently there are established users that think that anything posted in the answer section is an answer, maybe if we cut the problem at the bud and make sure that the answer is answering the question such cases are reduced.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks for your participation. I am basing my proposal on quite a large number of observed "questions-where-an-answer-should-be". Some of them additionally indicate that the posters are not even aware that the order of posts is unpredicatable (using prhases like "above answer"). All of them match the "your participation to this discussion" interpretation better than the "Your Answer" reality. I hope to contradict the interpretation by repeating the word "question" and by pairing it closely with the word "asnwer". Thereby to stress the Q/A design to contrast the forum perception.

Comment: "_Your helpful answer_"

Comment: @Cœur You are nicely more optimistic than I am. I am with you, but I would settle for any answer. :-)

Comment: @Yunnosch Hoping to improve this through reinforced connections... Nice explanation, well said. While I'm not optimistic it would work, I do like the idea.

Comment: Something to possibly take in to account here is that question titles are often poor. A lot of people seem to treat the question title like it's e.g. an e-mail subject line rather than a question. For example, if the actual question is *"How can I crank a widget with a C spanner?"* or *"Why doesn't my C spanner crank the standard widget?"*, they'll write *"Cranking widgets in C"*. If people want to know what to put in the answer box, what they should really be doing is reading the entire question body. "Question at the top of the page" or the title itself seems a little misleading.

Comment: @Radiodef True, I see. I will add something to the question referring to this. Thanks.

Comment: Yunnosch: In reply to *It works well for short actual questions...*, that question really needs a renaming edit...

Comment: Yunnosch: the longer one you intentionally made up to be horrible but plausible

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Hmm, I guess it is a compliment. Thanks. I have seen questions (titles) like that - hope you agree.

Answer (score 12):

Expanding my earlier comment into an answer, with a few variations:

> Your answer to *"Making a simple program, how to I make it so blank/spaces input doesn't count/add to it"*

-

> Your answer to the question *"Making a simple program, how to I make it so blank/spaces input doesn't count/add to it"*

-

> Answering the question *"Making a simple program, how to I make it so blank/spaces input doesn't count/add to it"*

Comment: I wonder if this would translate into "I don't know the answer to this" posts. If you've looked at the Q&A on Amazon products, you've seen these types of "answers", presumably left by people who thought that they were *required* to answer for whatever reason.

Comment: @Shepmaster Interesting point. But, taking Kendras example, how would that more often be triggered by the proposed change? Also, I think I would appreciate a wave of "I don't know." answers to all the "my question is..." answers I currently see. Just for a change, it would be refreshing.

Comment: Your answer to the question, "Making a simple program, how to I make it so blank/spaces input doesn't count/add to it" Comma makes it look better

Comment: @Shepmaster That could be mitigated with a button that says "I don't know", which hides the answer text box.

Comment: As I said already, I actually like the idea in this answer. It is worth being considered if/when something is changed in this area. I see however a little catch, which I explain in my most recent edit to the question. It is the reason why I do not accept this answer, even though I like it.

Comment: I am also not entirely sure what accepting an answer to a "feature request" question would signify. I would appreciate a link to a useful explanation/discussion. For the time being, I think I would accept an answer which proposes the most convincing and detailed implementation or even something quite different with the same intended effect but plausibly better chances of success and/or less change effort for the devs.

Comment: @Shepmaster I've also seen those non-answers on Amazon. But never on SO. "I don't know the answer to this" on this site would probably be immediately flagged for deletion.

Answer (score 9):

I propose to change the title to "Your Solution"

This is just as short as "Your Answer" and should make clear that posting a new question is not the right thing to do. 
A formulation with the word "answer" could always (even if the question is included) be understood as a participation in an ongoing discussion. There, one might want to respond (= answer) to something previously posted, potentially with a new question.

Comment: An interesting new angle. Thank you for joining in. "Solution" might be helpfully far away from "participation in discussion". The downside is that it breaks alittle the connection to the "Q/A design"

Comment: Maybe "Answer with your solution" (?)

Comment: @Yunnosch, fair enough, the suggestion shouldn't be buried in a comment. Done :)

Answer (score 3):

I like [Christopher's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370586/your-answer-to-the-question-at-the-top-of-this-page/370657#370657) as it points to what's expected on the answer box. But I feel it may be a bit unclear: *"Your Solution"* to what?

I'd suggest *"Answer with Your Solution"*. This is a site where people post questions, that box in the bottom is reserved for Answers that solve the problem:

<kbd>[image: how the phrase would look on the site]</kbd>

Comment: What do you think of a combination, e.g. "Answer with your solution for the question or problem" ? I somehow feel that the "at the top" is not needed in this phrasing, due to your idea to use "solution". But I would still like to reinforce the Q/A design.

Answer (score -3):

I doubt that rephrasing a single label can possibly avoid misinterpretation by many different people of varying cultures and languages.  As soon as a new phrase is implemented, there will certainly be a different subset of users who will likewise misinterpret the new phrase, especially if it contains more words and more complex grammar than the very basic "Your Answer".

Further, if they are treating SO like other forums, it is likely they don't even pay attention at all to the labels and instead rely on their intuitive experience with any other similar interfaces (enter text, click button below text... no reading comprehension necessary).

The question, or rather suggestion, already had an answer which primed everyone's response to focus only on rewording the title, but let's consider alternative solutions to the problem.  Some possibilities...

- Give new users limited comment ability.  Perhaps 1 comment per question or 1 per day, or a comment which expires if it doesn't get an up-vote or a direct response (via @username by a reputable user).  I know this has already been considered in the past, but perhaps it would be easier to handle rogue comments than invalid answers.
- Provide limited translations made available via an obvious "language icon".  I don't mean any sort of site-wide localization or full translation, just for key help pages and prompts.
- Be more explicit in the new-user prompt.  I get that this contradicts my initial concerns, but if nothing else works, then I think being more direct could be more productive. Something like...

> This is **not** a chat room.  Do not post answers with only follow-up questions or incomplete ideas.  Only post solutions that answer the original question.  Submit all other responses as comments.