# Make it clearer that the "Answer Your Question" button is not for adding more information to the question

Tags: feature-request, edits

After you have asked a question and you decide you want to add more information you see the following button below your question:

> [image]

I've blockquoted it to show how much space there is around this button, at least on the question I picked to use as an example. Even if there is typically less vertical space available there's certainly enough horizontal space for another button/link with a bit of explanatory text.

The words on the button should be enough to indicate that you don't click this if you want to add more information to the question, however, people still use it to do just that. The "edit question" link is way up there at the top of the page and may not even be visible if there are other answers, which may contribute to this state of affairs.

Can we have an "edit your question" link next to this button, perhaps with some words that will encourage people to use the right option?

There is a popup you get when you click the button:

[image]

But while that mentions editing, there isn't a way to go straight to editing from there either. You have to hit "cancel" and then find the edit link.

An edit link on that dialog would probably be useful too.

The same applies for commenting (or responding to requests for clarification), the dialog tells you you can do this, but doesn't direct you to where you can do it.

Comment: Surely the space around that button is determined by screen size, I know on my 1366x768 laptop I can barely fit a question on the screen, let alone have that much room by the answer button

Comment: @NickA - ah, I must have just got lucky with the question I picked.

Comment: There is already a popup saying *"**Comment** if you're trying to respond to an answer."* and  *"**Edit your question** if you need to add more details."* that requires you to click a second button saying "Yes, I want to post an answer." before opening the answer textarea...

Comment: @Holt, yes there is, but people don't read those. I believe having the "edit question" link visible on the page will help.

Comment: @ChrisF If people don't read this, this means that people basically click on any button they see, so I am not sure that adding a second button would help.

Comment: @Holt the popup may be misunderstood by users that don't know how the site works, they might read it as "Are you sure? Valid reasons to use this button are for example: commenting on other answers, adding details. Cancel if you don't want to do any of those things, otherwise press the button."

Comment: Just hide that button behind a huge paywall, wrong self-answer rate will decline drastically

Comment: You want to *edit your question* but you find and click a button labeled **Answer Your Question**. That button-click opens a dialog titled **Are you sure you want to answer your question?**. And you are again about to click a button labeled **Yes, I want to post an answer** ... Then you confirmed, to be not eligible to post on this site. ;D

Comment: You mean, besides the words “answer your question”? Hard to imagine how the word “answer” could be unclear or ambiguous regarding its actual meaning. Oh well, I guess it couldn’t hurt to add more text that nobody reads.

Comment: @CodyGray, clearly people *aren't* reading or are misunderstanding the text in both the button and the dialog, otherwise we wouldn't be seeing the volume  of non-answers that we do. Having more signposts should help and certainly isn't going to hurt.

Comment: "An edit link on that dialog would probably be useful too." If time is to be invested I think this makes a lot of sense...

Comment: Do we know the stats of how big of a problem this is? I suspect the actual solution will depend on that. If its a thing that rarely happens, we might as well keep flagging and deleting them, but if it happens a lot then we should clarify further (with e.g. Cris' answer)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I don't have figures, but I delete the various types of non-answer (edits, comments) most days and I'm one of 20+ moderators.

Comment: @ChrisF sure, I suspected this is a real problem, if a mod raises it, it has to be because it gets to the point of being bothersome, but real metrics (if obtainable) should make your point stronger

Comment: couldn't the existing "edit your question" in boldface become a link to actually edit your question?

Comment: @JDL - that's what's suggested in this answer - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385283/59303

Comment: @ChrisF it's *part* of what is suggested in that answer — one might wish to include an edit link without such an extensive redesign of that part of the UI.

Answer (score 64):

The dialog box could look like this:

> #### Are you sure you want to answer your question?
>
> - [Yes, I have solved my problem and want to leave my solution for future visitors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385272/make-it-clearer-that-the-answer-your-question-button-is-not-for-adding-more-in#wmd-input)
> - [No, I want to add information to my question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/385272/edit)
> - [No, I want to reply to a comment or to an answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/376604)
>
> <sub>[cancel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/385272)</sub>

Comment: Fixed it for you. If you use HTML ID `#wmd-input` you will give focus to the answer area

Comment: @Michael: Thanks! -- Though it doesn't work for me, maybe because I already posted an answer? -- Ah, if I open a new answer box, then the link works. Cool!

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's an edge case. Perhaps your proposed dialog would have to a different variant for that case as well. "Are you sure you want to answer your question **again**?", "Yes, I have an alternative solution", "No, I want to edit my previous answer", etc ... The 'Add Another Answer' button does that to an extent already, but the implementation is pretty crappy.

Comment: Users who ignore the hint **"Answer your own question"** three times, won't read the text of three options as well. They will only see **"Are you sure?"**,  **"Yes"**, **"No"** and **"No"**, and therefore just click on "Yes". And then we are on the same situation again.

Comment: @MA-Maddin: You make the assumption that everyone understands English as well as you do. People don't ignore the text, they misunderstand it.

Comment: I like this suggestion - maybe put the two No options first, to make the Answer option even less prominent?

Comment: @CrisLuengo If they don't understand what the word "answer" means, then what's the chance they'll understand the rest of the text (let alone be able to compose a meaningful question or an answer)?

Comment: @DanMašek: "answer" means "reply" to a lot of people. See [this other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377616/7328782). They've gotten a question in a comment, and want to reply to it, and therefore hit the button that says "answer", and then another button that says "answer". They're reading the buttons, but understanding them differently than you or I.

Comment: @DanMašek [Wiktionary's definition 1 for _answer_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/answer): "A response or reply; something said or done in reaction to a statement or question."  So the forum-minded users looking to post a reply understand the English meaning of "answer" just fine; it's Stack Overflow that has attached a specific meaning.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom "forum-minded users" -- i.e. those that didn't even bother to read the first few sentences of the [tour]? When has it become OK to just barge in somewhere without any concern for the rules and customs? Why do we try to accommodate such users? Ignorance is not an excuse.

Comment: Maybe we need a better onboarding process, where the workings of SO need to be hammered in and quizzed (would that even work on a website?), and any transgressions punished swiftly. But I see how this is unlikely given the continuing pursuit of quantity vs quality.

Comment: @DanMašek We are not trying to accommodate the helpless users; we are trying to accommodate our volunteer moderators, by steering the helpless users away from littering so the mods have less trash to pick up.  I would also like to see better onboarding and I agree SO won't build it; the next best thing is to try to mitigate the damage.  (I think we are mostly in agreement here.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom OK, fair point. (Although I have my doubts this will make much difference anymore)

Comment: Where is the EDIT button in your proposal? It's not good UX.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah.. I now understand the real problem. So this and the other meta question could be merged into one question focusing on the "answer" issue and not on buttons, dialogs and user education :)

Comment: @MA-Maddin: Yes, but you'd have to convince people to remove the term "answer" from a "question and answer" site... :)

Comment: Touché! So this will get bigger. The site must become a "Question and Solution" website ;)

Comment: @DanMašek the quiz idea is already discussed in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252829/brief-educational-quiz-before-posting-first-questions-in-popular-tags https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359196/interactive-challenge-for-how-to-ask-agreement ?

Comment: Or just remove the "yes" and "no" altogether. The text are clear enough (with the risk of having good user parse more things on the page)

Comment: @user202729 Was literally about to say exactly that.

Answer (score 13):

This question is a more specialized version of the wider 
[Educating new users not to ask questions in the answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377598/educating-new-users-not-to-ask-questions-in-the-answers), only focusing on the one who actually asked the question.

I'd say that the way to handle this is exactly the same as in [my answer to the other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377620/6451573).

> So why not plaster
>
> ### This box is reserved for answers to the problem, not for discussion
>
> when those new contributors, with a registered account, see the answer box ?

For having deleted a lot of those non-answers, I can say that self-answered non-answers are a small part of the non-answers like "did you find a solution? I have the same issue", which are a way bigger problem.

If some time/money could be spent on the subject I would suggest to add a popup when answering (self-answering is already pretty much covered) for new users (low reputation).

And let's face it: some are so desperate to talk/solve their urgent problem that they'll happily ignore it. But if it's not too much hassle, that would filter out a significant part of non-answers.

Answer (score 8):

It's already very clear, particularly with the popup.

Any further bikeshedding is timewasting as it only panders to those who do not read this stuff, which is (by definition) pointless.

Meanwhile, suggestions like Cris's (though well-intentioned, and the wording is great) make the popup waaaay more wordy and cumbersome for those who actually do care.

Just continue deleting answers-that-are-not-answers. Dev time is better spent elsewhere.

Comment: dev time would be well-spent making it clear that the answer box is for _answers_ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377598/educating-new-users-not-to-ask-questions-in-the-answers. We delete "I have this problem too" "answers" every day.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Clearer than labeling it "Answer"? What level of incompetence are we aiming for here? What sort of meaningful contribution can users like that make here?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not sure what you were getting at, but on that topic I'm hoping for social change (i.e. moderation policy) not any particular dev activity, as the answer box is already very clearly labelled and the tooltip over the "add comment" link already tells people what not to do (yet they continue to do so anyway, some -- including certain moderators -- with pride). Plus frankly it's blantantly obvious what our model is and why. Sorry if I missed the mark, bit drunk.

Comment: In fact yes on second reading it seems like you are replying not disagreeing, soz. My position on the misuse of both the answer and comment section is well established :)

Comment: @DanMašek let's be pragamatic: a LOT of people are answering like they answer to someone, not to a question. you and me are aware of what the "answer" box is for; but let's face it: a lot of people are used to regular forums and use it to reply (specially when they cannot comment, because the "add comment" button is inactive

Comment: @DanMašek I wouldn't call it "incompetence". For people coming here with experience in forums, it seems very natural to just make another post for clarification. Heck, I can barely even think of other Q&A formatted sites. GameFAQs has something similar with **Answers** (which aren't too popular), Atlassian has some product that looked like a knockoff SO, and maybe Quora? So, there isn't a great deal of sources for "transferable skills" when it comes to Q&A. Also, being unfamiliar with the tools of the website doesn't have a direct relation to contribution value.

Comment: @VLAZ Any FAQ in the world is in this format. Kinda.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can't actually think of any FAQs that users post and answer.

Comment: @VLAZ But the resulting format is the same and humans should have sufficient cognitive ability to observe how to arrive at that format, especially with over a million extant examples

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure it's super clear this is an FAQ format. There is a message box you have and you can post that. Even calling it "question" and "answer" means little, since even traditional forums sometimes use "answer" as a synonym to "post".

Comment: @VLAZ: There is a question, then answer(s) to that question. It's Q, and A. The same way on the street you will ask someone a question, then get an answer to that question. I don't know how much clearer it could be...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the fact that it's *not* clear should be evidence that...it's not clear. It's circular, I know, but clearly there is a problem with people misunderstanding this. Therefore, clearly it's not clear. Saying it is, doesn't change the fact the format is misunderstood.

Comment: @VLAZ What I'm saying is that the problem with understanding is not so much in the concept or the wording, but in the people. Because the concept and the wording are both absolutely crystal clear and pretty much as simple as they could be. The issue is not clarity; it is people (a) not thinking, and/or (b) not caring. And you can't fix either of those things by changing words. You ignore that possibility in your proposition _"clearly there is a problem with people misunderstanding this. Therefore, clearly it's not clear."_.

Comment: "Answer" is also a synonym for "respond"...

Comment: @Stobor No, it isn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit I'm no expert, but [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/answer) and [Roget's Thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/respond) say it is. While **in the context of questions and answers** that is not the preferred sense of the word, in general it is valid to interpret "answer" as "respond".

Comment: @Stobor: That's because answering is a specialisation of responding. But they're not synonyms. As for your links, the first only mentions "respond" in the definition of "answer back" (which is a totally different word from "answer", oddly enough), and the second is verrrry vague connections (always is).

Comment: @LightningRacesInOrbit From my first link: answer (VERB) 1. *Say or write something as a reaction to someone or something.* Synonyms: reply, **respond**, say in response, speak in response, make a rejoinder, rejoin

Answer (score 3):

The answers above seem to have a lot of disdain either for the OP or for the newbie user.  I'm not sure why ... but it appears to be a lot of rephrasing to the old "RTFM" grumpiness old guys like me remember from back in the days when software actually *had* manuals.

But I think the respondents' emphasis on the popup dialog is misplaced.  The point here is not (or ought not be) so much to deter users from misusing the "answer" button; rather, to increase visibility of the "edit" option.  On my monitor, that option shows at the bottom of the post in a smaller-than-the-rest, grey text:

[image: The edit options ... nearly invisible!]

Just turning those options into colored buttons with larger text would, I think, solve the problem for a lot of users who *aren't* complete idiots but may not have the best vision on the planet.  Placing those options in screen proximity to the "Answer" button, even more so.

Comment: I think I am only half with you. I fully agree with your suggestion! But I do not think it makes the OP and answered wrong. I think I want *both*, a more visible edit button and a clearer answer your own question dialog box

Comment: "The answers above seem to have a lot of disdain either for the OP or for the newbie user" could you elaborate? because from my end it looks like the opposite: some newbie users / OPs don't care about the "no comment until 50 rep" rule or "no questions in answer box".

Comment: "Don't care" is not synonymous with "don't see obvious options."  All I'm saying is that presenting options that are equally visible/accessible would separate those who miss the cues, from those who really don't care about the rules.

I'll be honest ... I *do* care about the rules, but the first time I used the forum I had to hunt for the "edit" option myself.  I did hunt, but not everyone's as careful.  That doesn't mean they're idiots or scofflaws.

Answer (score 3):

How about displaying extra button on OP own questions:

[image]