# How should I handle questions where there is a clear problem that has multiple possible causes?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497168/not-able-to-click-on-the-element-on-a-popup-even-though-it-is-getting-highlighte) today, and looked to see if I could answer it. Most SO questions go something like this:

> Asker: I have this problem.
>
> Answerer: Here's a solution.

This question, though, goes like this, all in comments:

> Asker: I have this problem.
>
> Me: Does this solution work?
>
> Asker: No.
>
> Me: Does this solution work?
>
> Asker: No.
>
> Me: Does this solution work?
>
> Asker: Yes.

It's not quite so spartan, there is a lot of clarification going on, and I feel like we're getting close to a solution. Even though their question is clear, there's no way for anyone, asker included, to find the issue in one pass.

Still, we end up with a ton of *possible* answers in the comments, all of which *may* help someone else in the future. I don't want to post them all as separate answers. Maybe a single *here's some stuff you can try* answer? Flag to close as *too localized*?

Comment: slightly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions

Comment: What was unclear / missing from the question that made you didn't offer the last solution as the best fit? Maybe an edit of the question could solve that.

Comment: The asker has a specific problem but it could be caused by a few different things. We're in the process of ruling them out.

Comment: Flag it as _too broad_.

Comment: It says you're a new contributor, and yet you ask about closing using the "too localized" reason, which hasn't been available since 2013...

Comment: Creating good Q+A with lasting value to thousands of programmers almost always require co-operation between the asker and the answerer(s).  A chronic problem is that the asker is very rarely interested in that goal, just here to get his problem solved.  Asking him to update his question is reasonable but don't expect miracles.  Best if you know how to edit the question yourself, posting the answer is now no longer a problem.  If you don't know how then best to move on.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Check their profile, they've been a member since 2013. They just get the badge since this is their first meta post.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think John's right. I love StackOverflow, but I very rarely run into a problem where SO hasn't already answered, which is a very good thing.

Comment: "there is a clear problem that has multiple possible causes?" -- The question would be clear if it asked "Is there a problem?" Since it attempts (poorly -- it's just a statement of what's wrong) to ask how to actually fix it, and you had to go through multiple iterations to reach a working solution, I'd say it's quite unclear (lacking significant amount of relevant information needed to answer it).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems to be that the problem the asker is detailing can't be reproduced due to there not being a minimal reproduction of the code.  Those questions should be closed, because there's not enough information in it to be able to help the asker, and you have to resort to guessing, as you did.

In these cases, you're better off moving on to a question that *does* have all the information needed to answer it.  Once you have to start guessing what the solution might be, that's a good sign that something is missing.  Downvote, vote to close, if you can, and move on.

Comment: I'd add that it's quite reasonable to leave a comment asking the user for the specific additional information that is needed for the question. While the close reason will tell the OP that there's not enough information to reproduce the problem, if a knowledgeable user reading the question can identify specifically what more is needed, leaving a comment can be quite beneficial. Such information can help the OP focus on the information that's actually needed. It also reduces the effort that other users need to put into the question to determine if all the needed information is present.

Comment: I agree with both of you. Probably the best thing to do is ask for clarification but flag to close as "too broad". Give them a chance to research a bit more then come back to ask for a reopen. They get feedback, and quality control keeps doing its job.

Comment: @ChrisAkridge No, missing MCVE is usually the better close reason, especially since these are typically debugging questions.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to generally downvote, that should be a separate decision. A question can be insufficient but still salvageable and useful, having the OP demonstrate his efforts.

Answer (score -1):

As a fairly recent joiner to SO, I would really advocate against the answers above that state, in effect, "not enough information means it was a bad question, just kick it to the curb."  Unless SO is to become a place where only experts can exchange information, the rest of us are often going to need the back-and-forth to even learn what, in fact, constitutes a "complete" question.  The process of diagnosing the question is part of the learning curve.

Furthermore, I can testify that several times as I've searched SO for answers to my own issues in R, the answer that actually solved *my* problem has NOT been the answer that worked best for the OP, but rather another one.  Please don't take steps to crimp this sort of diversity of opinion and creativity of solutions ... it would seriously compromise the value of SO as a resource to us who aren't already magicians.

Comment: If there is a back-and-forth between trying to answer the question and the OP refining the question, then closing is the most merciful thing that could be done to preserve any value in the question or future answers. No one comes to Stack Overflow to see a bunch of guesses.

Comment: One thing to note is that closure is not an end state; it's meant to prevent answers until the question itself is fixed.  Once the asker edits the question, it can always be reopened.  There's a review queue dedicated to reviewing questions that might be worth reopening, and closed questions that are edited are added to it.

Comment: There do exist "beginner" questions which are well-researched and well-written, and therefore add to the knowledge base of high quality questions and answers. A *limited* amount of back-and-forth is inevitable, and what comments are for. But the onus is on the asker to edit their questions with the clarifications brought out by the comments. Also incumbent on the asker is to provide what was previously attempted and failed to work. This reduces the amount of comments like those "Does this solution work?" comments alluded to in the question.

Comment: I think the disconnect between DanM and fbueckert here is very telling. According to DanM, new users think that closure (which has now even been re-branded as "on hold") means "just kick it to the curb", which is not and has never been the case. (It's true that many bad questions get closed, but closing does not intrinsically mean it was a bad question.) I think this indicates that there is a need for better documentation or communication of some kind, precisely so that new users don't develop these kinds of misconceptions, which are ultimately harmful to everyone.

Comment: @DanM: Just to be clear: the *intended* flow of "back and forth" goes like this: (1) user A posts a question, (2) user B adds a comment asking for clarification, (3) user A *edits* their question to clarify, (4) user B (or a moderator) *deletes the comment*. That has always been the *intention*... but unfortunately very rarely the reality.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a question reopened. They must exist because there is a reopen queue but AFAICT the perception is a closed question is closed forever.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden that description makes sense, and it is in fact what has happened in some of my own questions ... but it happened organically, not through any guidance I ever saw.  And I've seen a wide variety of seasoned users, some who dismiss the newbie with the equivalent of "come back when you get it right" and others who provide helpful guidance.  If the intention is to create better users, then documentation such as you describe (for example: "you didn't provide sample data, here's a link to how to do that") would be a good addition.

Comment: @DanM: That's all well and good, but where should such documentation live? We have pretty strong evidence that new users don't read the existing documentation (such as the tour) which has been distilled to be as easy to digest as possible. We have magic links like `[mcve]` to link users to information about what needs to be in a question. We have the magic `[edit]` link which is a link the user can click on to edit their question. We put a giant banner in front of new users asking them to take the tour. There's already lots of docs; the trick is in getting users to actually *read* the docs.

Comment: (To be clear, my previous comment isn't directed at anyone in this conversation; people who are willing to engage on Meta are already way ahead of the average user on the main site, in terms of understanding how Stack Overflow works and what it's for. That's great! Please keep it up. And if you can find ways to help more new users learn how to have a positive experience here, please do!)

Comment: @gman: I have no idea what tags you follow, but I've seen lots of closed questions get reopened (and in fact, sometimes questions go back and forth between closed and opened several times). Dupe-hammered questions can and do get reopened with a single vote from a gold badge holder; I've done it myself.

Comment: @DanielPryden Maybe we can send askers whose questions are closed a notification that details how they can get it reopened?

Comment: @ChrisAkridge: There's already the banner underneath a closed question, which already mentions some of this; if you have a suggestion for how to improve that text, I'd start a `discussion` about it here on Meta and try to gather community support.

Comment: @DanielPryden I'm more than happy to be the dummy here (even though some others don't appreciate and have down-voted).  You mentioned the tour ... I didn't know there was one, just spent 5 minutes clicking around the site and finally found it under the "help" question mark. When I first registered as a user to ask a question about R, I never saw anything about a tour (and I *do* RTFM). So while it's there, I only just read it now. Maybe that bar on the left (Home, Questions, Tags, Users) needs another link for "For New Users?"

Comment: @DanielPryden as to your question "where?" I think it relates in part to the discussion under my reply to <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385272/make-it-clearer-that-the-answer-your-question-button-is-not-for-adding-more-in/385306?noredirect=1#comment698608_385306">this thread</a>.  Short version: that edit link is easy to miss.  So are many other things, if you don't know how/where to look for them or even what to look for.

Comment: @DanielPryden an illustration: I came to SO to fix problems in R.  Early on, I didn't know how to provide data to illustrate my code (using mtcars doesn't always work, neither do command-generated datasets).  I have since learned two ways to do so: one with `dput` as suggested by a helpful user, another by making a dummy CSV and pasting it into the code (figured that out myself). I've searched using every version of keywords I can think of, and I can't find a thread on SO that says "so you need to provide data, here's how."  Not my problem anymore, but I bet others are like I was.

Comment: @DanM: Regarding the downvotes: Since votes on Meta don't affect reputation, if you make a post on Meta that suggests a change, you'll get downvotes that mean "I disagree this change should be made"; that doesn't mean that the post is badly written or problematic at all. Regarding clearer repro steps: there have been lots of discussions of this sort of thing in the past. For example, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366424. If you have a concrete suggestion, please open a question on Meta rather than just continuing in the comments here! I'm not a mod, I'm just an ordinary user.

Comment: @DanielPryden OK, I did.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385967/finding-environment-tag-specific-help-menu-proposal