# Finding Environment- (tag-) specific help - Menu Proposal

Tags: feature-request

The R community has an excellent instructional thread at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I can't replicate search terms that will find this thread, nor is it linked from the Help section of the SO menu. The generic help page [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provides some similar guidelines, but not nearly enough detail to enable a new user to follow them (it doesn't even mention providing sample data, btw). For that fraction of new users who care about following directions, it would help to be able to *find* them.

I can think of a couple ways to accomplish this:

- Ideal would be to add an option "For Beginners" to the left side of the screen where we now have "Home, Questions, Tags, Users." Under "For Beginners" would be ***domain-specific*** (i.e. tag-specific, but what tags?  [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) in this case) links to guides such as the one I linked above.
- Some other forums I've been on have "sticky" threads that stay at the top of a subject-specific list.  If SO included such an option, the above "How to" should be made into a sticky thread when listing the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag.
- An option to restrict the "Help" page menu and search to only references relevant to specific tags would also help.

Bottom-line take-home is that the Tour and the generic Help pages are so generic as to be minimally helpful.  At least one community - R - has developed vastly more useful domain-specific reference material but it's really difficult to find.  These requests are to simplify finding domain-specific help.

Comment: Are you aware of the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)?

Comment: How would the site know which domain-specific tag they need to show in the side-bar for a user?

Comment: Just be careful with *Some other forums*. SE sites are not forums, we are better not compared to those.

Comment: @yivi I was not.  That page has a lot of what I want, but finding it is (clearly) not intuitive.  I never would have thought to go under "Tags" to find help on the domain ... I went under "Help" and searched the search bar.  So yeah ... the content of that page, found under "Help" or "For Beginners" would solve the problem.

Comment: @rene, ideally with some equivalent of a "Home" page for a specific domain.  It would probably need a separate class of tag for major programming domains, for example R, Python, C#, whatever.  Context-sensitive help is a fairly common concept, though it does require some hierarchy of tags or indices.

Comment: Visibility could be improved. Right now you can find it on the top of the [tag question list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), under the "learn more" link. Problem is: when would you think it would be appropriate to show this information more prominently? Many (most?) users that are listing questions by tag are looking for questions to _answer_, not to _ask_ questions. So this info is not particularly relevant to them. Maybe when asking, but questions usually have multiple tag, and not all tags have useful info pages...

Comment: @yivi exactly.  That listing is not helpful for restricting answers.  It'd really need to be what I mentioned above ... a class of tag that has an attribute of "domain" or "root" (not sure the right term).

Comment: feels related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262823/wouldnt-tag-inheritance-make-sense

Comment: Tag wikis have so little visibility, which is a shame because of the work some have put into them. If only there was a long ignored feature request out there suggesting they be made much more discoverable.... But, hell, at least we have a new user notification now.

Comment: @rene, only marginally related.  That meta is about tag hierarchy in its own right; this one is about being able to find domain-specific help, with tag hierarchy being one possible component to a solution, but not necessarily the best one.

Comment: Related: [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/215552), [How to improve question quality of new Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320877/215552).